# Keep refreshing page until a specific word disappears

Tags: javascript, tampermonkey

I want to keep refreshing the website that displays `closing` text until this specific word disappeared, but nothing I've tried seems to work:

```
var YourTarget = "closing";
var RefreshTime = 1;
setTimeout(function(){
    if ((document.body.outerHTML).indexOf(YourTarget) == -1) {
       new Audio('https://www.soundjay.com/mechanical/sounds/machine-gun-02.mp3').play();
    }
},

RefreshTime*1000);    

if ((document.body.outerHTML).indexOf(YourTarget) !== -1) {location.reload(); };
```

Comment: Could U paste all script and example page on which it should work ???

Answer (score 0):

Chances are,

```
if ((document.body.outerHTML).indexOf(YourTarget) !== -1) {location.reload(); };
```

this code might be executing even before the dom is fully loaded. try putting this block in setTimeout. e.g.

```
setTimeout(()=>{ if ((document.body.outerHTML).indexOf(YourTarget) !== -1) {location.reload(); };},3000); 
// giving 3 secs for page to load
```

Comment: i want if (YourTaget) existe keep refresh, if not existe stop refresh